# Is there a way to disable images view on tensor board or remove them from event files?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm trying to design system with sensitive data which cannot be seen by people who develop machine learning based on this files. They working with TensorFlow and pyTorch. Is there any way to cut off this data from event files (would be great) or modify/configure tensor board to disable view this images?

Comment: Are you looking for solution to disable images tab in Tensorboard ?Please clarify.